# Leaflet shows both tile layers on zoom out

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to add two tile layers and a control to switch between them. Here is the code:

```js
const layer1: L.TileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'OpenCycleMap'
});
const layer2: L.TileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'OpenStreetMap'
});

L.map(SOME_DIV, {
  center: [54.1109, -115.5322],
  zoom: 5,
  layers: [layer1, layer2]
});

const baseMaps: Record<string, L.TileLayer> = {
  'Layer2': layer2,
  'Layer1': layer1
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(this.__map);
```

When the map is initialized, I briefly see Layer 2 before Layer 1 covers it. Also, if I zoom out, Layer 2 renders before Layer 1 covers it. I noticed that the attribute text at the bottom-right lists both attributions. If I then select one in the control, it only shows a single attribute and the problem disappears.

So, it seems that both layers are added, with Layer 1 on top. Layer 2 loads first then Layer 1. I want only one layer to show by default with a control to switch between them.

Here's a demo: https://gifyu.com/image/SuuzJ

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by only adding one layer on map initialization.

Is there a better way?